# Google Plus GoogleApiClient connect() without account selection dialog

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm working on integrating Google+ sign-ins into an app, and I have it mostly working now. Following the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

I was able to add a "Sign In with Google" button, integrate the `GoogleApiClient` from Play Services, and allow the user to sign in to the Google account of their choice.

However, in order to comply with the Google terms of service, I also want to provide a way (in a different activity) for them to completely disconnect their Google+ account from the app. According to Google's documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#revoking_access_tokens_and_disconnecting_the_app

This is a simple matter of calling `Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect()` with the connected `GoogleApiClient`. Problem is, that requires that I have a connected `GoogleApiClient` in the first place.

The process for getting such an object is outlined in the first link: Use `GoogleApiClient.Builder` to build the client object, call `connect()` on it, and use the appropriate callbacks to detect connection success or failure. But if the user has more than one Google account on their phone, then `connect()` leads to an immediate failure requiring me to call the resolution intent which will pop up a dialog asking them to pick which account they want to use.

But that won't work for this case, because they've already signed in to Google+, so I should already know which account to use. Remember, at this point, all I need to do is create a `GoogleApiClient` object signed in to the account they logged in to previously, so I can then pass it to `Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect()`. But I have no idea how to do that.

I've looked through the documentation and searched every combination of words I can think of to explain this issue, but so far I have found nothing. Is there any way at all to instantiate `GoogleApiClient` with a specific account instead of requiring the user to pick from the list of existing accounts? Or, if not, is there some information saved to Preferences that I can access to get a token to the account they have already authorized in my app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course, as soon as I post this I stumble across the answer.

For anyone curious, here's how you do it: you just need to add one more step to the GoogleApiClient builder; call the `setAccountName()` method to specify which account you want to build the api client object for. So this:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                       .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                       .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                       .addApi(Plus.API)
                       .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                       .build();
```

Becomes this:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                       .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                       .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                       .addApi(Plus.API)
                       .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                       .setAccountName(<gmail address>)
                       .build();
```

And then it works.

Comment: Thank you very much I was searching this method for hours!

Comment: That saved my day!